# Slow performance of COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Im working in MySQL, and want to count the number of occurrences of people buying a particular product. Therefore, I use the following query:

```
SELECT o.pid AS person, a.article_group_id AS ag, COUNT(o.pid) AS my_count
FROM vda.clustering c
LEFT JOIN vda.orders o ON c.pid=o.pid
LEFT JOIN vda.articles a ON o.aid=a.id
WHERE c.cluster=1 AND c.cluster_round='0'
GROUP BY person, ag
```

The output is correct, but it takes 8 seconds to retrieve this table.

```
person  ag  my_count
1       1   1
7       0   3
13      0   2
13      7   2
...
```

If I do not count the numbers, but just retrieve the data with the query below, it only takes 1 second. Is there another syntax that I am unaware of to accelerate the counting?

```
SELECT o.pid AS person, a.article_group_id AS ag
FROM vda.clustering c
LEFT JOIN vda.orders o ON c.pid=o.pid
LEFT JOIN vda.articles a ON o.aid=a.id
WHERE c.cluster=1 AND c.cluster_round=0

person  ag  
1       1
7       0
7       0
7       0
13      7
13      16
13      36
13      11
13      16
...
```

EDIT: Additional information:

My tables are created using the queries below. The articles contain information about the products. The orders couple the persons with the articles they have bought. I have separate tables (not shown here) in which I translate for instance brand_id into a brand proper.

```
"CREATE TABLE `persons` ("
"  `id` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `first_name` varchar(64), "
"  `last_name` varchar(64), "
"  `email` varchar(64) NOT NULL, "
"  `gender` enum('M','F','U') NOT NULL, "
"  `birthday` date, "
"  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), "
"  UNIQUE KEY (`email`) "
") AUTO_INCREMENT = 0, ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['articles'] = (
"CREATE TABLE `articles` ("
"  `id` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `article_nr` varchar(20) NOT NULL, "
"  `article_group_id` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `brand_id` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), " 
"  UNIQUE KEY (`article_nr`), "
"  FOREIGN KEY (`article_group_id`) REFERENCES `article_groups` (`id`), "
"  FOREIGN KEY (`brand_id`) REFERENCES `brands` (`id`) "
") ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['orders'] = (
"CREATE TABLE `orders` ("
"  `id` int(11) NOT NULL, "
"  `date` date, "
"  `pid` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `aid` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `price` float NOT NULL, "
"  `discount` float NOT NULL, "
"  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), "
"  FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`), "
"  FOREIGN KEY (`aid`) REFERENCES `articles` (`id`) "
") ENGINE=InnoDB")

TABLES['clustering'] = (
"CREATE TABLE `clustering` ("
"  `pid` int(8) NOT NULL, "
"  `cluster` int(8), "
"  `cluster_round` varchar(32), "
"  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`, `cluster_round`), "
"  FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES `persons` (`id`) "
") ENGINE=InnoDB")
```

The execution plan with indices on cluster,cluster_round as explained in the comments enabled:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  c   ref cluster_ci  cluster_ci  103 const,const 24624   "Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE  o   ref order_pid   order_pid   4   vda.c.pid   1   NULL
1   SIMPLE  a   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 4   vda.o.aid   1   NULL
```

Comment: One thing you could try is to change the left joins to inner joins.  Left joins have to do more work than an inner join and in this case all of your orders and articles should exist so an inner join is a better fit

Comment: I changed LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN, and now it is horribly slow. I canceled the query after 100 seconds, it was still not finished.

Comment: Can you identify which fields are indexed? Are your indexes maintained regularly?

Comment: My only indexes are the primary keys in each table, which is 'id' for each table. Is there a general recommendation which columns you should index?

Comment: Indexing the foreign keys used in those joins would make a difference `o.pid` `o.aid` `c.pid`

Comment: I tried that now using "CREATE INDEX cluster_pid ON vda.clustering (pid)", but it still needs the same amount of time. Is it by the way normal that you get the message: "0 row(s) affected Records: 0 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0 9.594 sec"?

Comment: maybe try covering index "CREATE INDEX cluster_ci ON vda.clustering (cluster,cluster_round);"

Comment: That saves considerably! Down to 2.8 seconds.

Comment: Can you post the table declares and some sample data please (and do an explain of your query and post the results of that). I am not 100% sure I understand you setup, but you say you want to count the number of people buying a particular product. You count o.pid, which is the orders. What is the product? I would have guessed from the name it is stored on the article table but not certain.

Comment: You have given a declare for persons which is not in your query, while your query contains clustering for which there is no declare. Is clustering a view?

Comment: My mistake. Clustering is also a table. I have added it now to the list above.

Comment: The execution plan would be useful

Comment: cluster_round is varchar. Why do you compare it to an integer?

Comment: Execution plan is added now. I changed the query to search for '1' instead of 1 in cluster_round.

Comment: Did you change your sql? In the first you do `c.cluster_round='0'`'. In the second `=1`' Further what is the relation between cluster and cluster_round. Wouldn't it be better to have a primary index on pid,cluster? Does it help if you change the order of the tables, so select from orders and left join articles and cluster?